# How to store daily/monthly snapshots on Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

we need to store daily and monthly snapshots of some of ours database.

It's not backup, we need to store the data so to analyze them later and to see how they evolve during the time.
We still don't know exactly what sort of queries we will need in two months, for starting we need to track some evolutions of our user base, so we will save daily snapshots of users and other related collections.

We are thinking to put all the stuff on Google BigQuery, it's easy to put data on it and easier to make queries on that data.

We will create some tables, one for each set of data we need, with all the needed columns, plus an extra one that will contain the date on which the extraction process was done.
We will use this column to group the data by day, month, and so on.

An alternative approach could be to create a dataset for each .. well set of data, and one table every time we need a snapshot.
I honestly don't know what is the better between these two, or if there are better options.

Comment: Hi, We're facing the same problem. How did you manage to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say which is best for you since I don't know your needs or cost requirements.

However, with the "create some tables, one for each set of data we need, with all the needed columns, plus an extra one that will contain the date on which the extraction process was done" method, you could run queries that will allow you to see what has changed for your users over time. For example, you could say, for a particular time slice, the average activity of a particular user over time.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the motivation behind that choice.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late, but for future readers: you are probably looking for [date-partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables). It corresponds exactly to this use case, and there's a straightforward example in the documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

You can now create table snapshots in BigQuery.

You can only use the `bq` command line tool for now.

See here -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-create#creating_table_snapshots

Comment: Thanks for reply. It looks much better than all others. But is it possible to take a snapshot by API, not UI?